# How to select multiple columns without deprecated ix in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In python, for data slicing in DataFrame in package **pandas**, *.ix* is already deprecated from pandas 0.20.0. The official website offers alternative solutions with either *.loc* or *.iloc* to do the hybrid selection (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html). The *.index* could help extract multiple rows. By contrast, the *columns.get_loc* seems can only select one column at most. Is there an alternative function available that can be used to extract multiple columns in a hybrid manner using *.iloc*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, function is called [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) and return position of columns or index by list of names.

Use it this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'a':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'b':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'c':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'd':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
}, index=list('ABCDEF'))
print (df)
   a  b  c  d
A  4  7  1  5
B  5  8  3  3
C  4  9  5  6
D  5  4  7  9
E  5  2  1  2
F  4  3  0  4

cols = ['a','b','c']
df1 = df.iloc[1, df.columns.get_indexer(cols)]
print (df1)
a    5
b    8
c    3
Name: B, dtype: int64

df11 = df.iloc[[1], df.columns.get_indexer(cols)]
print (df11)
   a  b  c
B  5  8  3

idx = ['A','C']
df2 = df.iloc[df.index.get_indexer(idx), 2:]
print (df2)
   c  d
A  1  5
C  5  6
```